# Copying folder with all subfolders and files from internal storage to user selected location using storage access framework

Tags: android

I try to copy a folder with all its contents from an app-internal location (e.g. `context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)`) to a user-selected location somewhere else (I don't know where, as the user selects the location). So technically I want to mimick `source.copyRecursively(targetDirectory)` where the targetDirectory is not a `File` but a SAF uri.

It works for a single file, but when I try to create a new folder all the files and folders are copied into the user-selected folder instead of keeping the file hierarchy.

Here's the copy function:

```kotlin
private fun copyFolder(source: File, targetDirectory: Uri) {
    when {
        source.isDirectory -> {
            // Create a new directory below the target directory with the name of the source directory
            val newTarget = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, targetDirectory)?.createDirectory(source.name)
            if (newTarget == null) return
            
            // Copy all files & directories from the source folder into the new target folder
            source.listFiles()?.forEach { entry ->
                copyFolder(entry, newTarget.uri)
            }
        }
        source.isFile -> {
            val target = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, targetDirectory)?.createFile("application/image", source.name)
            context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(target)?.buffered()?.use { output ->
                source.inputStream().buffered().use { input ->
                    input.copyTo(output)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how the function is called

```kotlin
private val exportLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree()) { uri: Uri? ->
        copyFolder(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES), uri)
    }
    
exportLauncher.launch(null)
```

Now all files and folders within `source`, no matter how deep down in the folders, get created under the top level directory which the user selected. E.g.

```
source\
        A\
            img1.jpg
            img2.jpg
        B\
            C\
                img3.jpg
```

ends up as

```
source\
A\
B\
C\
img1.jpg
img2.jpg
img3.jpg
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your copyDirectory method?  You're calling copyFolder.

Comment: it's a typo in the example code above, thanks